# How using a var local variable in a closure prevents the compiler from doing smart-cast for this variable?

Tags: kotlin, casting, closures

How using a var local variable in a closure prevents the compiler from doing smart-cast?

I read that If we use the local (var) variable in a closure, then it is no longer smart-castable, because now it's kind of like a property: it can be modified from somewhere else, so the compiler can no longer make guarantees about its type.

Can someone make an example of this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an interface:

```
interface Callback {
    fun onEvent()
}
```

Then within a function, if you create an implementation of the interface that modifies a local variable in the function, the variable is *captured* by the interface.

```
fun myFunction() {
    var x: Int? = 4
    val myCallback = object: Callback {
        override fun onEvent() {
            x = 5
        }
    }
    x ?: return
    val y = 2 * x // error, smart cast is impossible.
}
```

Since it is captured, the local variable isn't really just local any more. The interface that modifies it could be passed to some other function that calls it and modifies your captured variable. Since the compiler doesn't know how the interface will be used, it will refuse to smart-cast variables that are captured by interfaces.

Variables are also captured if modified in a lambda, for the same reason. The compiler doesn't know how often and when the lambda will be invoked.

Contracts should eventually resolve this issue for inline lambdas that are only used immediately, at least I think it should. Contracts are still an experimental feature and it doesn't seem to prevent this particular smart-cast error.

Comment: first of all thanks :)  Secondly, i understand almost all the code beside the last line `val y = 2* x` , which cast should be here? i thought smart cast is only relevant for `is` & `as` statement? In addition the compiler isn't smart enough to check if there is a call to some function with the interface as an argument between the moment of the check and the moment of using the variable?

Comment: Smart-casting also applies to null checks. `?: return` is a null check. Since it returns from the function if the variable is null, for a non-null variable that is not captured, it would be able to smart-cast it from `Int?` to `Int`. And yes, the compiler isn't smart enough to see that you don't do anything with the function or interface that captures it. But there would be no reason to create such an interface or function, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Tenfoud04, thanks -- again :) But the check ?: return , how long is relevant? because between the ?: return and the val y = 2 * x, x could be set to null somewhere

Comment: If you set it to null, the compiler sees it and so the null-check no longer applies after that line of code where you change it. This is assuming it is not captured.